# Need To access Web application which is hosted in Azure MSAL in android webview by passing access token

Tags: android, webview, azure-ad-msal

We are having two application one is deployed in web and secured using msal now we have made another mobile app and we want to access that web application in android mobile app. After successfully authenticating android mobile app i launch web application. It again ask for sign in.
I tried to pass the MSAL Access token in header to webview where website url is loading but nothing changed it again requested for sign in.
Is there a way i can pass MSAL android access token to Web application and access it without again sign in request?

App is in development

Smartphone (please complete the following information):

Pixel
Android 11
-Chrome
2.0+
Stacktrace
No Stack trace.

To Reproduce
Login in mobile app. Open any web app which is msal secured in webview. Pass the access token. even after being part of sso that webapp is asking again sign in

Comment: You might want to explain which of the [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) supported Authentication Flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) you are attempting.

Comment: We are using Authorization code flow. its working fine for mobile app but when we are passing same auth code to web app hosted in webview its not working. I am not sure even if this is feasible to do that.